# Connecting to Mongo Atlas from local Apostrophe cms code

Tags: javascript, mongodb, apostrophe-cms

I have enabled connection from anywhere 0.0.0.0/0 on Mongo Atlas.
In apostrophe code, in the file **data/local.js**
I added the following code :

```js
module.exports = {
  modules: {
    'apostrophe-db': {
      uri: 'mongodb+srv://clustername.mongodb.net/dbname?retryWrites=true'
    }
  }
};
```

Tried 
**mongodb+srv://admin:@clustername.mongodb.net/dbname?retryWrites=true** 
as well.

I see the following log :

```
/home/radhika/code/demo/demo-io/node_modules/apostrophe/index.js:67
    throw err;
    ^
MongoError: not authorized on admin to execute command { listIndexes: "aposCache", cursor: {  } }
        at Function.MongoError.create (/home/radhika/code/demo/demo-io/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:31:11)
        at queryCallback (/home/radhika/code/demo/demo-io/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:212:36)
        at /home/radhika/code/demo/demo-io/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:469:18
        at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this with Atlas. You are attempting to use a mongodb+srv URL, which is what Atlas recommends when using the MongoDB driver 3.6 or better. Apostrophe 2.x is currently on the MongoDB 2.x driver, so that doesn't work.

You need to use the older style of URL which you can see on Atlas if you click the "I am using driver 3.4 or earlier" tab instead:

```
mongodb://user:password@test-shard-00-00-some-address.mongodb.net:27017,test-shard-00-01-some-address.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=your-replica-set-name&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true
```

When I do it this way I have no trouble connecting.

If you are eager to use a newer version of the MongoDB driver, and the new style of URI, you can use the [apostrophe-db-mongo-3-driver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apostrophe-db-mongo-3-driver) module. But, this isn't currently mandatory to be successful with Atlas.

In Apostrophe 3.x we will of course use the newer generation of driver out of the box.

(One last FYI - MongoDB driver versions and MongoDB server versions are not the same thing. You don't need the 3.6 driver to connect to 3.6, for instance.)

Comment: I used this with actual credentials which have admin access and got the same error. I want to remove the unlimited access later, after I get the connection working.Is data/local.js the only file that needs to be edited?

Comment: Aha, it has to do with using the connection URI they recommend for a newer version of the mongodb driver Apostrophe doesn't currently ship with. See my updated answer.

Comment: Can you help me with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52039510/issue-connecting-to-mongo-atlas-from-apostrophe-cms-application-on-elastic-beans as well?

Answer (score 0):

If you click the `Connect` button from your cluster and choose `Connect your application`, and then choose driver version 2. This will give you an example of how to connect.