# Issue connecting to Mongo Atlas from Apostrophe CMS application on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, apostrophe-cms

I followed the instructions [here](https://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/howtos/deploying-apostrophe-in-the-cloud-with-aws.html) to deploy my apostrophe cms website to aws elastic beanstalk.

The mongodb doesn't have any whitelisting restrictions and is open to everyone.

I set db coonection string as an environment variable using

`eb setenv APOS_BUNDLE=prod-bundle APOS_MINIFY=1 APOS_MONGODB_URI=mongodb://admin:password@cluster0-shard-00-00-xyz.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-xyz.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-xyz.mongodb.net:27017/demo-io?ssl=true&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true`

I have added the same values to these environment variables using beanstalk dashboard as well.

The health status is "Degraded".

The logs are :

### /var/log/nodejs/nodejs.log

ERROR: There was an issue connecting to the database. Is it running?

```
/var/app/current/node_modules/apostrophe/index.js:67
        throw err;
        ^
MongoError: seed list contains no mongos proxies, replicaset 
connections requires the parameter replicaSet to be supplied in the 
URI or options object, mongodb://server:port/db?replicaSet=name
    at connectCallback 
(/var/app/current/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:523:23)
    at 
/var/app/current/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:418:11
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
ERROR: There was an issue connecting to the database. Is it running?
```

`

I am able to connect my local application to db on Mongo Atlas by editing data/local.js file using the same connection string.

I am able to access the db on mongo atlas from the terminal as well. What am I missing?

Comment: It looks like the environment variable is not intact by the time it reaches Apostrophe.

My best guess is that you need to escape characters in that "eb setenv" command, same as you would have to do for a regular setenv. Try `eb setenv 'APOS_MONGODB_URI=your-url-here...'` What's important here is the use of quotes around this parameter.

Comment: on use of quotes, application health status moved from degraded to severe. "eb printenv" is showing the correct values in both cases(when set with and without quotes).

Comment: Well, the best way to be sure is to write a script that simply prints that environment variable, and run it remotely on eb.